# how to Combobox get a data in notepad (run time) by mouse click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I making  a complete INTERNET explorer. I have done many option, a bookmark create a problem. Suppose I get a value by click new value from the notepad file, when done this according my idea. One problem is again faced me , every click get a duplicate value. how to avoid a duplicate data please guide me.
My coding part is :-

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int kkk = comboBox1.Items.Count;

   string path = File.ReadAllText("F:\\kmm.txt");
   string[] y = path.Split('\n');
   foreach (string kk in y)
   {
      comboBox1.Items.Add(kk);
   }
   // comboBox1.Items.Clear();
   string km = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
   wb.Navigate(km);
}
```

snap shot combobox::
[image]

Comment: On an add, you can load the existing entries as a List. Then, if (!(List.Contains(newEntry))){AddEntry(newEntry)}; Its pseudo, but should do the trick.

Comment: @AthomSfere but sir g i ask a add run time data in the combobox....i have many try ,help me about my problem

Comment: i am waiting a correct answer

Comment: Your saving to the file, too correct? Load, it once as AppDeveloper suggested to comboBox, each time you add turn the items in the combobox into a list or enumerate the comboBox for the same value. If its a duplicate, then discard the new entry. If its new, then add to the ComboBox and then commit the save to the file too.

Comment: @AthomSfere sir but can't add the data on the run time..

Answer (score 0):

Each time the `ComboBox Selection Index` is changed, Items are loaded from `F:\kmm.txt`.

You are applying a very wrong logic to load items in `ComboBox`

A better way would be load the item only once in the ComboBox in `Form_Load` event.

But in case you want the Add items to the ComboBox in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1` event you need to clear the items in `comboBox1` .

Try this way :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int kkk = comboBox1.Items.Count;

   string path = File.ReadAllText("F:\\kmm.txt");
   string[] y = path.Split('\n');

   // clear all existing items first
   comboBox1.Items.Clear();

   foreach (string kk in y)
   {
      comboBox1.Items.Add(kk);
   }
   // comboBox1.Items.Clear();
   string km = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
   wb.Navigate(km);
}
```

Comment: but sir i want to add on my click ..suppose my explorer is running state i add a bookmark and after then check out what i add.

Comment: I try your coding part but can't add a run time??