# Getting closest time

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of obects, each object has a TimeSpan property reprsesnting time of day.
I need to get an object which time is closest to the input value.

Should look something like this..

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>
{
   new MyClass() {Name="midnight", time= new TimeSpan(0,0,0)},
   new MyClass() {Name="noon", time= new TimeSpan(12,0,0)},
};

var testOne = GetClosest(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0),list); // returns midnight
var testTwo = GetClosest(new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0),list); // returns noon
var testThree = GetClosest(new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0),list); // returns noon
var testFour = GetClosest(new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0),list); // returns midnight (that's the tricky one)
```

Is there some elegant way of doing this?

**EDIT:** Of course the list should be passed, sorry.

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757136/find-the-closest-time-from-a-list-of-times?rq=1

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 - yes, but it's with times that aren't fixed to a particular date - which makes the solution much different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you would actually pass the list in too? It's not as efficient as it could be, but basically you want to map each pair (from the original time and the "target" times) to a range 0 to 12 hours, by trying both the existing time and "the same time the next day". For example:

```
public static TimeSpan GetClosest(TimeSpan time, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> targets)
{
    return targets.OrderBy(x => BestFit(x, time))).First();
}

private static long BestFit(TimeSpan x, TimeSpan y)
{
    return Math.Min(Math.Abs((x - y).TotalTicks,
                    Math.Abs((x + TimeSpan.FromDays(1) - y).TotalTicks));
}
```

Or using [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) to avoid a full sort but keeping simple (even simpler) code:

```
public static TimeSpan GetClosest(TimeSpan time, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> targets)
{
    return targets.MinBy(x => BestFit(x, time));
}

// BestFit as before
```

Comment: I'sorry but your metod is not working as i need. in last case (GetClosest(new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0));) it will return the noon (time-12), but i need it to return closest time which is midnight

Comment: @MAK: Well how on earth are you expecting it to know what options are available? You're declaring your list in the calling method, but not passing it anywhere. Basically, your question as originally asked is impossible. Or if you're actually referring to 10pm being closer to midnight, you should be more specific about that - I can try to fix that.

Comment: "Or if you're actually referring to 10pm being closer to midnight"-exactly what i meant, sorry again.

Comment: @MAK: Right, so you're *not* calling `GetClosest(new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0))` after all. It's really important to be clear on this sort of thing - you are after all asking other people to help you. Editing it now.

Comment: Thank you, Jon, it works as expected.You helped me very much.

Comment: @JonSkeet sir plz solve my problem.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325270/how-to-combobox-get-a-data-in-notepad-run-time-by-mouse-click/15325383#15325383.... I know u r genius man

Answer (score 0):

You might as well create an intermediate list (direct or indirect) for additional speed:

```
public static string GetFirstEqualOrHigher(TimeSpan time, IEnumerable<MyClass> targets)
{
    return list.First(x => time >= x.time).Name;
}

IList<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass() { Name="midnight", time = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0) }
    new MyClass() { Name="noon", time = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0) },
    new MyClass() { Name="midnight", time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0) },
};

var testOne = GetFirstEqualOrHigher(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0), list); // returns midnight
var testTwo = GetFirstEqualOrHigher(new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0), list); // returns noon
var testThree = GetFirstEqualOrHigher(new TimeSpan(13, 0, 0), list); // returns noon
var testFour = GetFirstEqualOrHigher(new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0), list); // returns midnight (that's the tricky one
```

Comment: That's just finding the first entry which is after the original time... which isn't the same as the *closest* one (8am should return noon, for example).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Not quite. I modified the times so that they're right in the middle. Simply finding the first that is after the middle finds the correct `Name`. Added a working example, and it shows the right names.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, although then the values in `MyClass` are wrong for any other purpose...